# Android: Icon doesn't appear in Navigation Drawer Activity using Vector Asset Studio

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to adapt a Navigation Drawer Activity created in Android Studio to what I want. 
I wanted to include an icon to an option "Places", so I changed the default icons and I used the Vector Asset Studio.

At the end the result was:

ic_menu_places.xml

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="(....)"/>
</vector>
```

activity_main_drawer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_places"
            android:title="Places" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
            android:title="Notifications" />
    </group>
```

[image]

The problem is that my icon of ic_menu_places doesn't appear on app. Comparing the xml of ic_menu_places and ic_menu_gallery of both there are no differences. Can you please tell me what is wrong to appear like that?

Comment: When talking imagery you should post screenshots of actual and expected bahavior.

Comment: @EugenPechanec you're right. I uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: @porthfind then try to clean and rebuild the project.